# Como resolver Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)?

Tags: php, mysqli

Pessoal estou fazendo aqui uma tela simples que faz uma consulta ao banco de dados, na primeira vez que criei deu tudo certo, mais agora apareci essa mensagem "Access denied for user '@'localhost' (using password: NO)".
Lembrando uso o servidor no MAMP e meu sistema operacional é o OSX.

No arquivo index.php

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "root";
$db_name = "exemplo01";
```

no model mdl_usuario.php

```
<?php
//função criada que deve ser usada no controller para
    function usuario_listar($conexao){
        $sql = "SELECT id, nome, idade FROM usuario ORDER BY nome";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        return $resultado;
    }
```

no controller.php

```
<?php

$titulo = "Manutenção de Usuários";

//aqui estou fazendo a conexão
$conexao = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)){
        echo "A conexão falhou, erro reportado: ".mysqli_connect_error();
        exit();
    }


    require ("mdl_usuario.php"); //chamando o model onde está as configurações sql

//designar quais serão as views a serem carregadas
//P = Listar, P = Cadastrar e P = Excluir

if(isset($_GET['p'])){ //aqui começamos a verificar os passos
    $passo = $_GET['p'];
}else{
    $passo = null;
}

    switch($passo){
        case"cadastrar"; //como não vamos cadastrar agora
            break; //pulamos
        case"excluir"; //como não vamos excluir pulamos
            break;
        default: //aqui vem o que iremos fazer no momento, que é listar os dados
            $dados = listarDados($conexao);
            require ("view_lista.php");
            break;
    }

//função criada para chamar os dados do database
function listarDados($conexao){
    //$resultado a variavel que vai chamar a função usuario_listar que deve foi criada no modell
    $resultado = usuario_listar($conexao);
//aqui é feito um array para organizar os itens
    $data = array();
//esse array tem um controle através de um while
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $data[] = array("id"=>$row['id'], "nome"=>$row['nome'], "idade"=>($row['idade']=="")? "--" : $row['idade'] );
    }
    return $data;
}

//esse arquivo sempre deve existir fora do switch pq sempre existira a conexão
@mysqli_close($conexao);
```

Comment: O seu banco possui senha mesmo?

Comment: Possui uma senha que já vem como padrão no MAMP

Comment: é só isso que aparece no erro?

Comment: Tente deixar a senha em branco... E consulte as perguntas no fórum, na barra de pesquisa. olha se algumas dessas lhe ajuda:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Access+denied+for+user+%27%40%27localhost%27+%28using+password%3A+NO%29

Comment: Sim, apenas isso, e o mais incrível que na primeira vez deu certo, dai hoje quando fui mexer apareceu isso.

Comment: Você pode redefinir sua senha de root. Tenha em mente que não é aconselhável usar root sem senha. Tirado de http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: Agora esta pior, nem consigo mais acessar o phpMyAdmin depois que tentei trocar a senha do root, que por sinal pensei não ter conseguido.

Comment: O que acontece quando acedes o mysql pelo console ?

Comment: Então @Edilson consegui resolver o problema de acesso, pois configurei manualmente o arquivo config.inc.php com a nova senha que eu tinha criado, portanto continua ocorrendo a mesma mensagem de erro citada no problema quando a minha aplicação tenta fazer conexão com a base de dados.

Comment: Você seguiu os passos [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno) apresentados ?

Comment: Sim, e continua a mesma coisa, fiz a mudança da senha e nada adiantou, não está conseguindo haver comunicação..... Eu irei criar uma outra aplicação de teste e verei se irá continuar a mesma coisa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, retirei as informações do index.php e passei para o controller, as seguintes:

```
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "new-root";
$db_name = "exemplo01";
```